# Maven non-parseable POM / Missing classes

Tags: maven

I'm using maven to compile a java project, and I'm getting errors saying it can't find classes in one of the dependencies. I've tried everything I can think of, and all the other contributors have no problems with it.

Here is the entire output with -X and -e

http://pastebin.com/rxgGYrTV

Comment: What exactly did you try? I would recommend erasing your local repository (~/.m2/repository)

Comment: Plus, you seem to be using linux-bundled maven package; I don't think it's a good idea - try downloading latest vanilla maven and putting it on classpath

Comment: I've tried removing the repository. I don't know how to get vanilla maven...

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

Answer (score 3):

Seems that your repository contents is broken.

`/Users/dev/.m2/repository/tc/oc/tracker/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata-kosgan10-repo.xml` seems to be no correct XML any more.

You may remove the repository folder (if unsure, rename it) and run the maven build again.